# Mounting a Nested SSH Location

Tags: ssh, mount

I have a server that is only SSH-accessible to machines within a network and my only access to that network from the outside world is a single publicly-SSH-accessible node.

Is there some way that I can mount the nested machine from the outside?

```
Me -> Public SSH-accessible Node -> Internal SSH-accessible Machine
```

Answer (score 2):

Use SSH tunneling:

```
ssh -L 2022:internalSshNode.com:22 externalSshNode.com
```

you may then make an ssh connection to the internal node using a local port:

```
ssh -p 2022 localhost
```

Comment: Or you can do a SOCKS proxy with ssh (-D <portnumber>) and "wrap" your ssh connection with tsocks.